# Who is Mark Shuttleworth, and how is he related to Ubuntu?

Tags: development, community

I am going to introduce Ubuntu to some new users (students in this case). Usually, I talk about [the history of Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37133/whats-the-history-of-ubuntu), how Ubuntu started, who has built Ubuntu in the past, and [who decides the road Ubuntu takes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68795/who-takes-up-decisions-prior-to-development-in-ubuntu).

Of course, you can't talk about the history of Ubuntu without mentioning Mark Shuttleworth. I would quite like to have a question on Ask Ubuntu to point new users to, so this is it!

Who is Mark Shuttleworth, and how is he related to Ubuntu?

Comment: [Wikipedia: Mark Shuttleworth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Shuttleworth) (Ctrl+F "Ubuntu") and [Wikipedia: Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)) (Ctrl+F "Shuttleworth")

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Mark Shuttleworth** is an entrepreneur from South Africa who founded the Ubuntu operating system through his company, Canonical.

- Before founding Canonical, he was the founder of [Thawte](http://www.thawte.com/), a company he founded in 1995 to provide digital certificates and internet security.  Thawte has since been sold to Verisign.
- Shuttleworth was a [Debian](http://www.debian.org/) Developer in the 1990s.
- Shuttleworth founded his company [Canonical LTD](http://www.canonical.com/) in 2004, a company dedicated to supporting free software.
- Through his company Canonical LTD, he founded the [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) operating system in 2004.  Ubuntu is a derivative software product of Debian.  Canonical still governs and supports the Ubuntu operating system to this day and Ubuntu continues to be a product based on Debian.
- He set up the [Ubuntu Foundation](http://www.ubuntu.com/news/UbuntuFoundation) in 2005 with an initial donation of $10 million USD of his own funds.
- He remained the CEO of Canonical LTD until 2010, when he stepped down to focus on other responsibilities within Canonical and Ubuntu.
- Shuttleworth is also famous for being the second ever self-funded [space tourist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_tourism) (funded a trip to space with his own money) and the first ever South African in space.

Comment: Whao, interesting, I never knew Ubuntu was Canonical's child from the beginning. I always assumed Canonical stepped in right around 10.04 and that's when UI changes began.

Comment: No but interestingly, 10.04 marked the first release where Shuttleworth *wasn't* CEO anymore and instead was focusing more on, among other things, product design.

Comment: @Flabricorn: the thought that some people think this never even occurred to me! Have an upvote.